# Extracting and saving data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

So I have this large text file and I have to extract some information from three of its columns. So the way I want to do it is by saving the index when the first quantity becomes greater than zero, using that index to start searching the second column to see when its value becomes constant, save that index and store that value until it stays constant in a matrix. For those few indexes, I also need to extract values from another column and save them.

Here's what I have for the code so far:

```
%Open a file 
filename = uigetfile(['*.dat'], 'Select file');
data = importdata(filename);

%Selecting Mach Number from the data 
Mach_Number = data(:,4); 
RPM = data(:,19);
Torque = data(:,20);
index1 = 0;
index2 = 0;
%Selecting a portion of Mach Number that corresponds to constant RPM
for i = 2:size(RPM,1)
    if (RPM>0)
        index1 = i;
        for j = index1:size(Mach_Number,1)
                if (-0.00001<Mach_Number<0.00001)
                    index2 = j;
                end
        end
    end
end
newMach = Mach_Number(index2)
newRPM = RPM(index1)
```

Comment: Have you thought about the Import Data option from Matlab? You can generate a script if you want to automate it afterwards.

Comment: What is the structure of your `.dat` file?